# Кэширование в GrapgQL в Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql

Необходимо кэшировать список врачей на главной странице, иначе spinner показывает каждый раз, когда переходишь с таба на таб.

Если приложение открывается впервые, приложение смотрит в кэш, там нет данных, он запрашивает с сервера и кэширует данные.
Если есть данные в кэш, то показывает с кэша, не обновляет кэш.
Кэш обновляется, только когда пользователь делает "pull down to refresh", чтобы вручную обновить данные.
Если пользователь закрывает приложение полностью, а потом открывает заново, есть данные в кэш, поэтому приложение показывает сразу данные с кэш, но в то же время делает запрос на сервер, чтобы автоматически обновить данные и записать в кэш.

Comment: https://ferrygraphql.com/docs/fetch-policies